# Allow string contains specific char from string

Tags: java, regex

i want check `String` if contains specific `char` from `String`.

How can I do this in `java`?

Thank you.

Example:

```
String inputString =HI, hoW aRe you?";
String allowChar ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,.?!0123456789 ";
```

Comment: please show some research efforts

Comment: Have you checked the api of String? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html
Just check what indexOf(char c); does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use : `inputString.matches("["+allowChar+"]+")` to check if your `inputString` contains only the characters mentioned in the `allowChar` tring

Comment: Use Pattern.quote() on allowChar first (in general case).

Answer (score 2):

int checkString(String inputString, String allowChar)

```
int len=allowChar.length();
int j=inputString.length();
for(int i=0;i<j;i++)

    for(int k=0;k<len;k++)

    if(inputString[i]!=allowChar[j])

        return 0;
    else

        return 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check by `regex`.

```
boolean match = inputString.matches("[a-zA-Z]+,\\.?! ]"));
```

Or iterate over your `String`

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++){
    String s = inputString.charAt(i) + "";        
    if (!allowChar.contains(s))
        // value is not contained...
}
```

Comment: The OP also want to match spaces, commas and exclamation mark.

Answer (score 0):

```
String inputString = "HI, hoW aRe you?";

try {
    if (inputString.matches("[a-z0-9,\\.?! ]")) {
        // String matched entirely
    } else {
        // Match attempt failed
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```